# Dynamically Add a Timestamp To Files in Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, dataflow

I've been working on a azure project, and I want to create a dataflow using a dynamic filename that contains timestamp.
for example , if the output is a file name 'A' -->  'A_YY-mm-dd_hh_mm_ss'
I already did that on a data factory using this link [Here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dynamically-add-a-timestamp-to-files-in-azure-data-factory)
but in this case I don't know how could I use it.
there is my data flow [image]

The input is an extract file( i did it with a copy data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer [this code](https://github.com/Kenji-H/beam-examples/blob/master/word-count-beam/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/common/WriteOneFilePerWindow.java). I tried to modify the `filenamePrefixForWindow`    method and I was able to achieve this. These were the changes I made -

```
public String filenamePrefixForWindow(IntervalWindow window) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        String month = String.format("%02d",(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
        String date = String.format("%02d",calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        int hh = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        String hour = String.format("%02d",(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0) ? hh:hh+12);
        String minute = String.format("%02d",calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        String full_date = year+"-"+month+"-"+date+"-"+hour+"-"+minute;
        String prefix =
                baseFilename.isDirectory() ? "" : baseFilename.getFilename();
        return String.format(
                "%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/output-%s", prefix,year,month,date,hour,full_date);
    }
```